# Simple code, yet its erroring?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
import java.util.Scanner;
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Syntax error on tokens, AnnotationName expected instead

^This shows up for both these lines. The only code before this is declaring a package (has semicolons)

Comment: Do you mean that's your *whole* code? You haven't included a class declaration anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

You need to show **where** that code is located. Those two lines should **never** be next to each other since the import statement goes **before** the class declaration and the Scanner declaration goes after the class declaration.

So instead of

```
import java.util.Scanner;
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
```

it should be

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyClass {
    private Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
```

---

**Most important**, please check out a Java tutorial since this is foundational knowledge that is required before you can progress. You can find a link to the tutorials here: [Java Info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info).

Answer (score 1):

Your scanner statement should be within class definition like:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test {//everything should be within class be it instance variables or methods that may act on/or not on instance variables.
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    ...
}
```

Comment: @Downvoter may i know the reason please.

Comment: Not sure who down-voted you, but I have reversed it.

Comment: Thanks @HovercraftFullOfEels Same with you. I dont know why people down vote without any reasons!